# Is it possible to not find the electric field from potential at a point that has three finite charges acting on it?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

I have a problem where I am to find the potential at a point $(0,0,z)$ which has three charges acting on it, $q$ at $(0,a,0)$, $q$ at $(0,-a,0)$, and $-2q$ at $(0,0,-b)$.

So I know that there is no point in calculating the potential in the $y$ or $x$ direction, because they either cancel or aren't there, so I just found the potential in the $z$ direction. Now once I find the potential I need to see whether or not the electric field $\vec E$ can be found from the potential. When I try this using $\vec E=-\nabla V$, and I'm not given then answer for $\vec E$ that is correct (although it does look very close).

From what I saw online I should be getting the same answer, and another stack exchange question: [Can the Electric Field - always- be derived from the potential?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/91459/can-the-electric-field-always-be-derived-from-the-potential) Talked about using Poisson's equation, which I am not familiar with, but from what I gather it's possible that it couldn't be found using potential. A peer of mine also is getting the same results I am, and I can't find any fault with my math.

Is it possible that I have a scenario where the electric field *can't* be derived from the potential?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The electric field can always be derived from the negative gradient of the electrostatic potential $$\vec E=-\nabla V$$ unless you are sitting at a singular point, like at the location of a point charge. Thus you should also be able to derive it that way on the z-axis (except for z=-b). In the present case, however, it is probably easier to use the known Coulomb formula for the electric field.

Note: The electric field can be calculated practically everywhere, there is no restriction in space.

Comment: Yes, I found the electric field from Coulomb, and I also needed to check whether or not the potential could be used to find it. Apparently it can! Thank you